# Woocommerce -- Adding Products with Javascript/PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom form that users make various selections before being presented with  products they can buy. I need to add some logic that if an input has been selected when the user adds a product to the cart, it will also add an additional product to the cart.

The input is 3 radio check boxes. Somehow I need to hook into the add to cart click and check the page to see if one of the radios has been selected and then add the appropriate product but I'm not sure where to start.

I know I'll need to have an action that runs something like:

```
WC()->cart->add_to_cart( 'product_id', 'quantity');
```

But I'm not sure how to hook into the initial add to cart click and how to check for the radios on the page.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Take a look here. This is the hook that is fired when adding to cart. [woocommerce_add_to_cart](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_add_to_cart/)

Comment: This is useful. The radio buttons are inputs, but they aren't built into a form that's being posted. How can I get that data within my function on the server side?

Comment: The inputs must be part of the single product form, or it will not be posted to the cart for processing, unless you don't rely on the "Add to Cart" Button and do so programmatically. Are these inputs on the single product page?

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of information to go off of here, but here is a few useful WooCommerce hooks to give you a starting point/ order of operations. When overriding any native action in WordPress or its plugins. You should use the hooks if available.

**Add the radio inputs to the single product before the add to cart is added (hook):**

```
add_action("woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button", "your_input_render_function_here");
```

**Add the new input data from the radio buttons to the cart item (filter):**

```
add_filter("woocommerce_add_cart_item_data", "your_filter_function_to_capture_data_here");
```

**Capture the data and render in cart (filter):**

```
add_filter("woocommerce_get_item_data", "your_cart_render_function");
```

**Finally, save the newly aquired data to the order (hook):**

```
add_action("woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item", "your_function_to_add_to_order")
```

This is one of many directions you can take, depending on your requirements. I recommend giving it a shot, and if you still have issues return with an example of your code.